# Horde installation failure CentOS 7

Tags: centos, webmail

I'm trying to install the Horde Groupware Webmail Edition 5 on CentOS 7 following this documentation, [installing horde with pear](https://www.horde.org/apps/webmail/docs/INSTALL#installing-with-pear) and the installation is failing on my step number 5.

1. pear channel-discover
2. pear.horde.org pear install
3. horde/horde_role
4. pear run-scripts horde/horde_role
5. pear install -a horde/webmail

Error I've:

```
[root@horde-test ~]# pear install -a horde/webmail
Unknown remote channel: phpseclib.sourceforge.net
Package "pear.horde.org/kronolith" dependency "pear.php.net/Date" has     no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/kronolith" dependency     "pear.php.net/Date_Holidays" has no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig" dependency "pear.php.net/Net_DNS2" has no releases
Package "pear.horde.org/Horde_Mapi" dependency "pear.php.net/Math_BigInteger" has no releases
horde/imp can optionally use package "channel://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/File_ASN1"
horde/kronolith requires package "pear/Date"
horde/kronolith can optionally use package "pear/Date_Holidays" (version >= 0.21.0, version <= 1.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 1.0.0alpha1)
horde/webmail requires package "horde/kronolith" (version >= 4.2.23,         version <= 5.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 5.0.0alpha1)
horde/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig requires package "pear/Net_DNS2" (version >= 1.3.0)
horde/imp requires package "horde/Horde_Mail_Autoconfig" (version >= 1.0.0, version <= 2.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 2.0.0alpha1)
horde/Horde_Mapi requires package "pear/Math_BigInteger" (version >= 1.0.2, version <= 2.0.0, excluded versions: 2.0.0)
horde/Horde_ActiveSync requires package "horde/Horde_Mapi" (version >= 1.0.0, version <= 2.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 2.0.0alpha1)
No valid packages found
install failed
```

And if I tried to install the requires packages I got this error:

```
[root@horde-test ~]# pear install Net_DNS2
No releases available for package "pear.php.net/Net_DNS2"
install failed
```

Any idea what is happening?

Thank you all